# .htaccess redirect partial url pattern

Tags: .htaccess

I am having issues with writing the proper redirect statement, and unfortunately can't rap my head around the syntax needed. Other questions have similar problems, but I can't figure out how to properly reuse the information in other posts.

I have a url: **www.site.com/.../CORE_Testing_5010** this unique.

I need the page to redirect to **www.site.com/core-phase**

The **...** could be multiple directories **/a/b/c/d/CORE_Testing_5010** or just **/a/CORE_Testing_5010**

Right now, I have 310 redirects for most of the possible directory combinations, but that is inefficient.

Some guiedence and explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /CORE_Testing_5010$ /core-phase
```

The regex pattern ignored everything before the last `/`, so there can be anything in front of `/CORE_Testing_5010`.

If you have rewrite rules, and using mod_alias (the `RedirectMatch`) is causing conflicts, then you can stick with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule /?CORE_Testing_5010$ /core-phase [L,R=301]
```

and it needs to be before any rules that do routing.