# How to redirect orginal url if partial url or short url come

Tags: javascript, php, url, redirect

I want to redirect url if partial url get like stackoverflow manage or other sites. Is that possible in php.

eg. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150608/htaccess-redirect-partial`

It automatic convert to orignal url

eg. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150608/htaccess-redirect-partial-url-pattern`

Comment: The important part of the url is the `id`, e.g. `yourdomain.com/questions/{id}/{slug}`. You'd have to check the `id` against a database and check if the `slug` matches the original `slug`, else redirect to the complete url.

Comment: @RasmusRosengren You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the url is the `id`, e.g.

```
yourdomain.com/questions/{id}/{slug}
```

You would have to check the `id` against a database and check if the `slug` provided matches the `slug` related to the requested `id`, if not, redirect to the complete url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using **`.htacess`**

```
# Permanent URL redirect 
Redirect 301 /questions/21150608/htaccess-redirect-partial /questions/21150608/htaccess-redirect-partial-url-pattern
```

Comment: I have millions of records. not possible to rewrite